# Bluez 5.3x and implementing Obex server issue

Tags: server, bluetooth, bluez

I implemented obexd from package Bluez 5 in order to receive files from remote Bluetooth devices. I was able to register profiles ftp and opc by dbus (**ProfileManager1**). But when trying to connect remote device the server on my local device doesn't start. Function **NewConnection** and other functions from AgentManger1 are not called at all. I use example code from src/main.c to start all stuff.

Is anybody have an experience with implementing obex server on linxu device. I am talking about programming it with Ansi C.

I stuck and will very pleased for any hint or example how correct start obex server.

Comment: I don't have specific example for OBEX. But you can refer A2DP/HFP implementation here: https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa/blob/master/src/bluez.c#L1063. It uses the same way to register it as external profile with Bluez over DBUS.

Comment: Thanks for help, I am going to check your example. It looks promising. I had to implement d-bus as well and even thought I did it somehow wrong but it must work. Dbus calls name_acquired and that calls register_profile(). So it seems to work. But nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Works OK now. My dbus lib config.h was incorrect.